# How to get ttk.Treeview.bbox to work correctly during instantiating?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tcl

The script below is meant to expose the visible top-level items id (i.e idd) of a `ttk.Treeview` widget. I created a method called `._show_visible_toplevel_iids` in the class to achieve this. I notice that this method (specifically the `.bbox` method of the `ttk.Treeview` widget) does not work correctly during the instantiation stage of the class. However, this method works thereafter, i.e. whenever the `ttk.Button` widget which runs the `._show_visible_toplevel_iids` method is manually clicked on by the mouse.

The following messages are printed out during instantiation:

```
all_toplevel_iids=('G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7', 'G8', 'G9')
visible_toplevel_iids=[]
children_iids=[]

all_toplevel_iids=('G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7', 'G8', 'G9')
visible_toplevel_iids=[]
children_iids=[]
```

The following messages are printed out when the `ttk.Button` is clicked:

```
all_toplevel_iids=('G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7', 'G8', 'G9')
visible_toplevel_iids=['G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
children_iids=[('F0', 'F1'), ('F2', 'F3'), ('F4', 'F5'), ('F6', 'F7'), ('F8', 'F9')]
```

**Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Is there a bug in tkinter itself?**

Test Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        BG0 = '#aabfe0' #Blue scheme
        BG1 = '#4e88e5' #Blue scheme

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, style='App.TFrame', borderwidth=0,
                           relief='raised', width=390, height=390)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Treeview')
        self.parent.geometry('470x350')
        
        self.setStyle()
        self.createWidgets(BG0, BG1)
        
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def setStyle(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('App.TFrame', background='pink')


    def createWidgets(self, BG0, BG1):
        # Treeview with scroll bars
        columns = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(10)]
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self, height=20, selectmode='extended', takefocus=True,
            columns=("type", "property A", "property B", "selected"),
            displaycolumns=["property A", "property B", "selected"])
        self.ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set,
                            xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky='ns')
        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='ew')

        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=True, anchor='w', width=100)
        self.tree.column('property A', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)
        self.tree.column('property B', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)
        self.tree.column('selected', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)

        self.tree.heading('#0', text="Type", anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('property A', text='Property A', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('property B', text='Property B', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('selected', text='Selected', anchor='center')

        counter = 0
        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.tag_configure(i)
            tliid = f"G{i}"
            self.tree.insert("", "end", iid=tliid, open=True,
                             tags=[tliid, 'Parent'], text=f"Restaurant {i}")
            ciid = f"F{counter}"
            self.tree.insert(tliid, "end", iid=ciid, text=f"Cookie", 
                             tags=[tliid, ciid, 'Child', "Not Selected"],
                             values=(tliid, f"{i}-Ca", f"{i}-Cb", False))
            counter += 1
            ciid = f"F{counter}"
            self.tree.insert(tliid, "end", iid=ciid, text=f"Pudding", 
                             tags=[tliid, ciid, 'Child', "Not Selected"],
                             values=(tliid, f"{i}-Pa", f"{i}-Pb", False))
            counter += 1
            
        # Button
        self.showbutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Show Visible Top-Level Items iid",
                                     command=self._show_visible_toplevel_iids)
        self.showbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self._show_visible_toplevel_iids()  # .bbox doesn't work correctly
        self.showbutton.invoke()            # .bbox doesn't work correctly 
        

        
    def _show_visible_toplevel_iids(self):
        tree = self.tree
        tree.update_idletasks()
        all_toplevel_iids = tree.get_children()
        visible_toplevel_iids = [i for i in all_toplevel_iids
                                 if isinstance(tree.bbox(i), tuple)]
        children_iids = [tree.get_children([i]) for i in visible_toplevel_iids]
        print()
        print(f"{all_toplevel_iids=}")
        print(f"{visible_toplevel_iids=}")
        print(f"{children_iids=}")

               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you call `self._show_visible_toplevel_iids()` inside `createWidgets()`, the frame has not been put into the window as the layout function has not been called on it yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a widget, it doesn't actually get displayed immediately. Instead, the widget (or at least its underlying graphical entities) isn't really created until it is mapped, and the request to do that happens when the application event loop becomes idle after the script-level part of the widget is created (assuming you've also put the widget in a suitable container up as far as a toplevel that is mapped; toplevels directly interact with the window manager and the root window). After that, there is a fairly complex interaction of events and callbacks while the toolkit decides what actual size and position to give the widget; until those are all done, you don't get useful information out of any bounding box queries. The processing is fast, but not instantaneous.

All this delayed processing is why Tk (and hence Tkinter) seems so fast and has done for 30 years; the complex bits run in the background.

More formally, once you get a `<Configure>` event delivered to the widget, you should be able to get bounding box info. It's probably best to wait for the event loop to go idle at that point as well in case some other event queued causes a resize as well; you won't be able to see the delay but it ensures that all queued events are drained before you start querying the finalized layout.

```
# Use this to do the initial call, instead of directly
self.tree.bind("<Configure>", self.__show_first_visible_toplevel_iids)

# and then this method
def __show_first_visible_toplevel_iids(self, e):
    self.tree.bind("<Configure>", None)
    # I *think* this is the right way to call after_idle
    self.tree.after_idle(self._show_visible_toplevel_iids)
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of putting `self.tree.bind("<Configure>", None)` into the event handler `. __show_first_visible_toplevel_iids` and then thereafter call the event handler `.__show_first_visible_toplevel_iids` again?

Comment: Essentially, after populating the `ttk.Treeview` widget with items, a `<Configure>` event will be generated. Knowing this fact, you binded this event to the event handler `self.__show_first_visible_toplevel_iids` which then allows the use of `.after_idle` method to trigger the `self._show_visible_toplevel_iids` command method of the `ttk.Button` widget. However, I think the line `self.tree.bind("<Configure>", None)` could be replaced with `self.tree.unbind("<Configure>")` so that future `<Configure>` events would not trigger the command method. Else it could be removed as it seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @acw1668.

I learned from you that during the instantiation of my App class, the geometry manager methods (i.e. `grid`, `place` or `pack`) of `self` (which is a `ttk.Frame` widget) typically is not yet activated. Consequently, the `self` and the `ttk.Treeview` widgets are not visible yet. Therefore the `.bbox` method of the `ttk.Treeview` widget did not detect any visible `ttk.Treeview` items.

To overcome this issue, I believe a **best practice** for customizing a widget class that consists of a `ttk.Treeview` widget is to not insert any items into the `ttk.Treeview` widget or use the `.bbox` method of `ttk.Treeview` during the class initialization stage. Rather, the insertion of items into the `ttk.Treeview` widget and any use of its `.bbox` method should be done after the customized widget class has been instantiated and positioned into the `Tk` window.

Test Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent=None, style='App.TFrame', borderwidth=0,
                         relief='raised', width=390, height=390)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Treeview')
        self.parent.geometry('470x350')
        
        self.setStyle()
        self.createWidgets()

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    

    def setStyle(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('App.TFrame', background='pink')


    def createWidgets(self):
        # Treeview with scroll bars
        columns = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(10)]
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self, height=20, selectmode='extended', takefocus=True,
            columns=("type", "property A", "property B", "selected"),
            displaycolumns=["property A", "property B", "selected"])
        self.ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set,
                            xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky='ns')
        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='ew')

        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=True, anchor='w', width=100)
        self.tree.column('property A', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)
        self.tree.column('property B', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)
        self.tree.column('selected', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)

        self.tree.heading('#0', text="Type", anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('property A', text='Property A', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('property B', text='Property B', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('selected', text='Selected', anchor='center')
            
        # Button
        self.showbutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Show Visible Top-Level Items iid",
                                     command=self.show_visible_toplevel_iids)
        self.showbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        

    def insert_treeview_items(self):
        counter = 0
        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.tag_configure(i)
            tliid = f"G{i}"
            self.tree.insert("", "end", iid=tliid, open=True,
                             tags=[tliid, 'Parent'], text=f"Restaurant {i}")
            ciid = f"F{counter}"
            self.tree.insert(tliid, "end", iid=ciid, text=f"Cookie", 
                             tags=[tliid, ciid, 'Child', "Not Selected"],
                             values=(tliid, f"{i}-Ca", f"{i}-Cb", False))
            counter += 1
            ciid = f"F{counter}"
            self.tree.insert(tliid, "end", iid=ciid, text=f"Pudding", 
                             tags=[tliid, ciid, 'Child', "Not Selected"],
                             values=(tliid, f"{i}-Pa", f"{i}-Pb", False))
            counter += 1
            
    def show_visible_toplevel_iids(self):
        tree = self.tree
        tree.update_idletasks()
        all_toplevel_iids = tree.get_children()
        visible_toplevel_iids = [i for i in all_toplevel_iids
                                 if isinstance(tree.bbox(i), tuple)]
        children_iids = [tree.get_children([i]) for i in visible_toplevel_iids]
        print()
        print(f"{all_toplevel_iids=}")
        print(f"{visible_toplevel_iids=}")
        print(f"{children_iids=}")
               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    app.insert_treeview_items()  # Do this after app has been gridded
    app.showbutton.invoke()      # Do this after app has been gridded

    root.mainloop()
```